# Fetch joined members list from group, xmpp;

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, groupchat

I'm trying to fetch joined member list from particular group based on room `JID`, there are couple of method exists, mentioned below:

- MultiUserChat.getMembers();  It return `XMPPError: forbidden - auth`
- MultiUserChat.getOccupants();   *It return self info only*
- MultiUserChat.getParticipants(); It return`XMPPError: forbidden - auth`

But none of working getting exception `XMPPError: forbidden - auth`, it seem there is something issue with privacy,which I'm not able to figure out.

*Note: JID the name of the room in the form "roomName@service"*

Comment: I believe getOccupants() is correct, but it should return more than just yourself (assuming there are others in the room of course...)

Comment: yes, you are correct, but I'm also surprised, does `Broadcast Presence for: Moderator/Participant/Visitor` in room effect to `getOccupants()`?

Comment: Yes, it will only return who is currently in the room. Anyone who is offlne will not be returned. To get offline members you can use getMembers() and the others, but depending on the server and its configuration, you may not have permission to view these lists.

Comment: But its not working as it has to, it only return self detail instead all joined member list.
[This is room detail](http://s23.postimg.org/q4j33kbnv/Untitled.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per xmpp documents room/group should be non anonymous to  retrieve all members list. So try to set anonymous = false in .yml or configuration file at server side or you can set that also in configuration while creating rooms.

Please not that  affiliation  should at-least member to retrieve member list

Answer (score -1):

```
Use this :

multiUserChatManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(XMPPConnection);
MultiUserChat muc =multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat("dopee@conference.104.155.155.5");
        try {
            List<Affiliate> admin=muc.getAdmins();
            System.out.println("Admin=====>>>"+admin);
            List<String> userlist=muc.getOccupants();
            List<Affiliate> member=muc.getMembers();
            List<Occupant> memBer=muc.getParticipants();
            List<Affiliate> owner=muc.getOwners();

            System.out.println("userlist=====>>>"+ userlist.toString());
            System.out.println("usercount=====>>>"+   muc.getOccupantsCount());
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```